# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list after used await

Tags: node.js, database, async-await

**app.js cutout**

```
console.log(await db.getUserByEmail("email@gmail.com"))
```

**database.js**

```
// Initialize Supabase
const { createClient } =  require('@supabase/supabase-js')
require("dotenv").config({path: "./index.config"})

const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)

class database {

    static async fetchUsers() {

        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select();
        
        if(error) {

            console.error(error);

        }
        if(data) {

            console.log(data)
            
        }
    }

    static async createUser(email, hashedPassword, gender) {

        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .insert([{ email: email, hashedPassword: hashedPassword, gender: gender },]);
        
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        
    }

    static async emailExists(email) {

        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select("email");
        
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            return true;
        }
        if(data) {
            
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log("["+i+"] " + data[i].email + " : " + "["+i+"] " + email)
                
                if(data[i].email == email) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
            
        }

        return true;
        
    }

    static async getUserByEmail(email) {

        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select();
        
        if(error) {

            console.error(error);
            return null
        }
        if(data) {

            data.forEach(user => {
                if(user.email == email) {
                    console.log(user.email)
                    console.log(email)
                    console.log(user)
                    return user
                }
            })
            return null
            
        }

        return null
    }
}



module.exports = database;
```

I want to get a user by his email in the database. But it gives me following error message instead:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

I also check other Stack Overflow's posts that say this problem is caused by a deprecated node version, but my version is Node.js v19.3.0.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Initialize Supabase
const { createClient } =  require('@supabase/supabase-js')
require("dotenv").config({path: "./index.config"})

const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)

class database {
    static async fetchUsers() {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select();
        
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        if(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    }

    static async createUser(email, hashedPassword, gender) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .insert([{ email: email, hashedPassword: hashedPassword, gender: gender }]); // <= removed comma between curly brace ( } ) and square bracket ( ] ) 
        
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
        } 
    }

    static async emailExists(email) {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select("email");
        
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            return true;
        }
        if(data) {            
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(`[+${i}+] ${data[i].email} : [+${i}+] ${email}`) //<= Also, used string interpolation just to be safe
                
                if(data[i].email == email) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;            
        }
        return true;       
    }

    static async getUserByEmail(email) {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select();
        
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            return null
        }
        if(data) {
            data.forEach(user => {
                if(user.email == email) {
                    console.log(user.email)
                    console.log(email)
                    console.log(user)
                    return user
                }
            })
            return null           
        }
        return null
    }
}


module.exports = database;
```